# Cloning a project in Android Studio causes gradle exception

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have ligdx/robovm/gradle/android studio project with core, ios, android and desktop subprojects. I wanted to clone android subproject and create very similar one (I named it android-full). I've copy-pasted android directory and renamed it as well as stuff inside it's (build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml). In settings.gradle I've added 'android-full' to the list. In build.gradle (root directory) I've copy-pasted project(":android") to project(":android-full"). When I'm trying to sync gradle I'm getting an exception:

> Error:exception during working with external system:

Full stacktrace from logs here:

http://pastebin.com/T2XUWtYN

A guy from libgdx forums even created github repo with demo project for me (with 2 android subprojects ofc). Gradle works on it without any problem. Here it is: https://github.com/piotr-j/doubledroid
But when I've copy-pasted source code from core/src and android/android-full (without build.gradle) I've immediately got the same exception. I also compared all gradle files with diff checker and they're almost the same (structure is the same as well as version of gradle, I only have more libs).

I use latest android studio (1.4) and gradle 2.4.

I've tried restarting android studio, doing everything again from scratch, deleting .gradle directory, messing in .idea configs and still the same exception, which isn't very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how, but I fixed the problem. I just imported it in Eclipse (with gradle plugin). Project appeared without any problem. Then I realized there were fix small bugs in code, cleaned & builded everything again. Then project worked, I closed it and opened Android Studio again. Then it just worked! Some gradle vs android studio bug I guess.